# Traversing directories and their sub-directories

Tags: c++, qt

I traverse directories and their sub-directories using this piece of code. I do it in order to get path of only one random file from each end-sub-directories and pass to next end-sub-directory. But, in my implementation, it traverses all the files in end-sub-directories.

For example, from `/cars/bmw/model1/` directory , it is enough to get just `/cars/bmw/model1/f.png` path.

```
QDirIterator it(selectedReferenceFullDirectory, QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);

    while(it.hasNext())
    {
     ...
    }
```

My sub-directories are like:

```
/cars/bmw/model1/h.png
/cars/bmw/model1/f.png
/cars/bmw/model2/q.png
/cars/bmw/model1/hb/a.png
/cars/bmw/model1/sed/y.png
/cars/audi/model2/sed/y.png
...
```

So, there is no certain number of sub-diretory. Since there are tons of photos inside the directories, while loop takes long time. Do you have any idea to have better performance? Thank in advance

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you need only a single file from a directory, I would suggest to iterate not over all files, but rather over sub-directories (using `QDirIterator::Subdirectories` flag). For each iteration I would get a single file from that directory and move the the next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose to iterate not over all files, but over sub directories only. For each directory just take a single file (randomly). Here is how I would do it (simplest solution):

```
QStringList randomFiles(const QString &path)
{
  QDirIterator it(path, QDir::AllDirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot,
                  QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
  QStringList filePaths;
  while (it.hasNext())
  {
    it.next();

    QDir dir(it.filePath());
    auto files = dir.entryInfoList(QDir::Files);
    if (files.size() > 0)
    {
      // Take the first file from each directory.
      // This might be a random file too, though.
      filePaths.append(files.at(0).absoluteFilePath());
    }
  }
  return filePaths;
}
```